# How to iterate over rows in a pandas dataframe and if the condition is met it is printed in the appropriate excel sheet?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I have a dataframe in which some columns are empty. I have a criteria in the if statement in which if some of the columns in each row are empty the whole row goes to the rejected datasheet starting from row 3 in the excel sheet. Otehrwise, it will be a row in the accepted datasheet starting from row 3 in the excel sheet as well. An extra thing would be to add borders to each printed row in each excel worksheet

Currently the whole dataframe is printed in each excel worksheet.

```
df = df[['Lastname', 'Firstname','Company','Title','Willing_to_share','Willing_to_introduce','work_phones','Work_email','Work_Street','Work_City','Work_State','Work_Zip','Personal_Street','Personal_City','Personal_State','Personal_Zip','mobile_phones','Personal_email','Note','Note_Category']]
##print(df)
## Lastname Firstname          Company Title Willing_to_share  \
0       Doe      Jane                                           
1   Malcoun       Joe  8/28/2019 14:29                          
2   Ramirez    Morgan                                           
3     Burki     Roman                                           
4      None    Jordan                                           
5      None                                                     
6  Zachuani     Reemo                                           
7    Suarez   Geraldo     
 Willing_to_introduce work_phones              Work_email  \
0                       5678743546        j@greenbriar.com   
1                             None        ceo@nutshell.com   
2                       3338765438      mramirez@nerdy.com   
3                       5468756098           burki@bvb.com   
4                             None  jordanw45490@gmail.com   
5                             None                   ronny   
6                             None                           
7                             None   

              Work_Street      Work_City Work_State Work_Zip Personal_Street  \
0        54 George street  Ridge Springs         VA    25678                   
1     212 South Fifth Ave      Ann Arbor         MI    48103                   
2              567 one st     Birmingham         AL    45678                   
3  546 fourteen street Nw         Dallas         TX    54678                   
4                                                                              
5                                                                              
6                                                                              
7       456 yellow street                                                      

  Personal_City Personal_State Personal_Zip mobile_phones Personal_email Note  \
0                                              3245687907                       
1                                                    None                       
2                                              6780431874                       
3                                              0983457690                       
4                                                    None                       
5                                                    None                       
6                                                    None                       
7                                                    None                       

  Note_Category  
0                
1                
2                
3                
4                
5                
6                
7                



columns=df.columns
for column, row in df.iterrows():
    if (column[0] != ' ' and column[1] != ' ') and ((column[2] != ' ' 
    and column[3] != ' ') or (column[2] == ' ') and (column[6] != ' ') 
    or (column[16] != ' ') and (column[12] != ' ' and column[13] != ' 
    ' and column[14] != ' ' and column[15] != ' ') or (column[8] != ' 
    ' and column[9] != ' ' and column[10] != ' ' and column[11] != ' ' 
    and (column[7] != ' ' or column[17] != ' '))):
        wb = Workbook()
        ws = wb.active
        wb2 = Workbook()
        ws2 = wb2.active
        for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False, header=False):
             ws.append(r)
             ws2.append(r)
             wb.save("Accepted Contacts.xlsx")
             wb2.save("Rejected Contacts.xlsx")
    else:
        wb = Workbook()
        ws = wb.active
        wb2 = Workbook()
        ws2 = wb2.active
        for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False, header=False):
           ws.append(r)
           ws2.append(r)
           wb.save("Rejected Contacts.xlsx")
           wb2.save("Accepted Contacts.xlsx")
```

In the image it is how the accepted contacts worksheet looks like right now with the data
[image: This is how the accepted contacts worksheet looks like right now with the data]

Comment: Can you please reformat your code so that it is properly indented?

Comment: Can you share a sample of both datasets and your expected outcome(s)? also instead of the lengthy if statement you can convert the blanks into pandas null values `NaN` and then use isnull on a subset of your columns?

Comment: It is only one data set with many rows. I want the rows to be divided over two worksheets. If a row passes the if condition it goes into the Accepted contacts but if it did not it goes to the Rejected contacts

Comment: if that's anonmyized data can you paste it as text and not an image? also we don't have your expected outputs?

Comment: I pasted the whole Dataset. What I want is the if statement will check each row in the dataset. If the row passes the if statement then it will be added to the Acceptedcontacts.xlsx staring from row 3. If not then it will be added to the Rejectedcontacts.xlsx starting from row 3